# viewControllerAtIndex in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying introduce a `UIPageViewController` into my application, tutorials use:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //Code
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

But **Xcode** I can't put `viewControllerAtIndex(index)`

[image]

What is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call function called `viewControllerAtIndex` (implicitly on `self`, or as a global function). But there is no such function. Hence the error message.

Comment: `self.viewControllerAtIndex` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you say it; the important thing is that you must _declare_ a function `viewControllerAtIndex` or you won't be able to call it. It isn't going to fall by magic out of the sky; you have to _write_ it.

Comment: You're right! Now, I feel like a big fool Thank you